# How to make correct table for category / subcategory / sub-sub

Tags: php, mysql, categories

I have on my other projects category and subcatecory.

At this time I have done this by a separate table for cat and subcatecory like this:

```
category
  id   
  catname

subcategory
  id   
  subcat_id   
  subcat_name
```

In my actual project I have to do more than a subcategory like this.

```
Internet - WebDesign - Php
Internet - WebDesign - Html
House - Garden - Machines
```

How can I do this. I think its not good to make 3 tables with the categories , subcategorie, sub-subcategories

Thanks for any suggestions how is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not make a single table:
cat_id,
text,
parent_id

if it is a top level category, parent_id is 0, otherwise parent_id is the cat_id of the parent. If you wanted a multi-lingual site, remove text column and have a seperate table with cat_id, language_id, text.

Comment: Thanks for this... And how can i show all the categories with a single select on the same page like this:

`Internet
 -WebDesign 
             - Php 
             - Html 
House 
      - Garden 
- Machines`

Sorry i hate the comment field of stackoverflow. I cant show it correctly with code

Comment: You will want a function, with a select query where parent id = $variable. Default the variable to 0. Then do a foreach loop inside that query, and in each cat_id, run the function with the cat_id as the new parent to find children. You can echo out <ul><li> format to make a list, and use css to make it a menu, or whatever you prefer. Hope that makes some kind of sense...

Answer (score 1):

1. Normal way is to have a parent I'd e.g.

   id  category parent_id

   ---

   1   cat      0

   2   blackcat 1

   3   dog      0
2. If you have well designed category ids, you might omit parent id e.g.

   id     category

   ---

   11     cat

   22     dog

   1133   pussy cat

   113352 pussy cat golden

And here are some SQLs:

```
SELECT * FROM cat WHERE id LIKE '11%'; ## get all cats
```